# "File's Owner" of a custom XIB

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder

If I create an individual nib file and load it in my viewcontroller and assign it to an ivar like so:

`self.loadingview=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"loading" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];`

Is it possible to create IBOutlets to any thing on it in the nib, like activity indicators? Would File's Owner be the viewcontroller, even though IB wouldn't know this, since it is made an object in code?

Is loading the nib the way I've done it the acceptable practice?

Perhaps the more acceptable practice is to also create a .h/.m, and use that as the class for the XIB, in which case File's Owner is the new custom class; i'd still need to use the above method in my controller, though, when creating the ivar from the custom class, right? Or is there a better way to do all this, without using the controller's xib?

UPDATE: Based on some answers, I did the following. I got rid of the `NSBundle` method above, and instead just do this:

`@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView*loadingview;`

In the nib file for this view, I click on File's Owner and change the `Custom Class` to my viewcontroller. Then I control-drag from File's Owner to the View and it links up fine.

I would assume at this point that I now have an ivar in my controller, `self.loadingview` that contains the information in the nib. However this isn't the case. I removed the NSBundle method, assuming the controller will now load the nib directly through the IB outlet, but the view in the nib does not show up and I have no control over it in the controller.

I had also removed this when I removed the NSBundle method:

`[self.view addSubview:self.loadingview];`

I'm not clear how the view actually displays at this point; and if it does, where in the view heirarchy it appears? perhaps it is behind other views. I tried this too:

`[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.loadingview];`

But the view just isn't there. In an effort to find it, I did:

`//[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.loadingview];`

`NSLog(@"index: %i",[[self.view subviews]indexOfObject:self.loadingview]);`

both with and without the commented part. I get this:

`index: 2147483647`

Comment: problem solved. i have learned that even when loading a view from a nib, you must still use `addSubview` for it to appear

Comment: Your edit makes this a radically different question. You should start a new question so that later searchers can find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just because you have created a nib and inside that nib hooked up the outlet on File's Owner does not automatically load that nib from your view controller.

You can use the `UINib` class for this:

```
UINib* nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"loading" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
```

Once you do `instantiateWithOwner:self`, the nib will be loaded and `self` will be used as the File's Owner and the view from within the nib will be connected to your `loadingView` property.

You still need to call `[self.view addSubview:self.loadingView]` to add it to the screen.

Comment: nice. your blog is nice too (I've commented there in the past). How is your method any different than just writing `[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"loading" owner:self options:nil];`

Comment: `UINib` caches the nib object so it's a bit more efficient. Other than that, there's probably not much of a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Interface Builder will know of the file's owner that you sent through the `owner:self` argument. What you need to do to make your `IBOutlet`s show up in Interface Builder is to set the correct class of the File's Owner in IB under the *Identity and Type* tab.

Comment: i have updated my question with my effort based on these answers, and while the IBOutlets appears and works in IB, the view itself doesn't seem to be controllable from my controller's ivar.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to create IBOutlets to any thing on it in the nib, like activity indicators? Would File's Owner be the viewcontroller, even though IB wouldn't know this, since it is made an object in code?

They wouldn't be IBOutlets, but yes, you can wire connections by hand. `IBOutlet` is an empty macro. It exists exclusively so that Interface Builder can find the properties you would like it to wire to. But the `IBOutlet` keyword has absolutely no impact on the runtime (it's not even seen by the compiler). Similarly `IBAction` is a macro that is replaced with `void`. Nothing about Interface Builder exists at runtime.

When the nib loader reads the nib file, it deserializes each object and then for each connection, it sends a setter message (`setFoo:`) to the connection target passing the new object. After it has finished that for every object in the nib file, it sends `awakeFromNib` to every object it created. Objects with a connection target of `nil` are sent to the "owner" (which is `self` in your example). Note that the file owner is not created by the nib loader. The nib loader has no control over the actual class of the file owner. It's up to you to make sure that the file owner responds to the `set...:` calls or you'll crash.

> Is loading the nib the way I've done it the acceptable practice?

I would not rely on `loadingView` being the first top-level object. The order of objects is not defined. Instead, you should use IB to wire the view to the `loadingView` property of File Owner.

> Perhaps the more acceptable practice is to also create a .h/.m, and use that as the class for the XIB, in which case File's Owner is the new custom class; i'd still need to use the above method in my controller, though, when creating the ivar from the custom class, right? Or is there a better way to do all this, without using the controller's xib?

The traditional way to do it is to have a `UIViewController` for each nib file in iOS. But that's isn't required. On Mac, `NSViewController` is pretty new and doesn't work as well as `UIViewController`, so there isn't as strong a tradition there. Hand-loading like I'm describing is more common there, though most things are still handled through `NSWindowController`.

If you want to do these kinds of things, [Nib Files](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html) in the Resource Programming Guide is required reading.

Comment: i have updated my question with my effort based on these answers, and while the IBOutlets appears and works in IB, the view itself doesn't seem to be controllable from my controller's ivar.